# Error in figures

Tags: graphics

Using this

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\columnwidth]{images/figure1}
        \caption{caption text for image here}
        \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Receive this errors:

> ```
> pdflatex> ! Undefined control sequence.
> pdflatex> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
> pdflatex> ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)
> ```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through `access.tex` that comes with the `ieeeaccess.cls` file, we can find the following line that corrensponds to the following output (in `access.pdf`):

```
\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){fig1.png}
{Magnetization as a function of applied field.
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption.\label{fig1}}
```

[image]

Applying this to your image we end up with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt)[width=0.8\columnwidth]{example-image}
{caption text for image here\label{<figure_label>}}
\EOD
\end{document}
```

[image]

With some dummy text added:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However this figure goes into to column. How can we have it only into one column?

Comment: @foc: I have edited my answer to show the output of the code if I add some dummy text. As you can see, teh image stays in a single column and does not interfere with the text in the adjacent column.